# How do I animate the jquery validation error message and highlight the field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a login page using jquery validation and am using the plugin animate.style for css animations.

I am trying to get the form field input box to highlight and the error message to fade in and appear underneath the text field. However, the code I've pieced together is very glitchy and I'm convinced can be improved.

As the input boxes are merge fields which include an icon I am not sure I'm targeting the correct placement.

**My form code looks like this:**

```
            <form class="js-validation-signin" action="login_check.php" method="post" name="loginform" id="loginform">
            
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-label" for="username">Username:</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="form-control form-control-prepended"
                           placeholder="Enter your username">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fa fa-user-alt"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-label" for="password_2">Password:</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control form-control-prepended"
                           placeholder="Enter your password">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fa fa-key"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit">
            </div>
```

**The validation code I am using is:**

```
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='loginform']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    errorClass: "invalid-feedback is-invalid",
    validClass: "is-valid",
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        //error.appendTo( element.closest(".form-group"));
        jQuery(element).parents(".form-group > div").append(error)
      },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).fadeOut(function() {
          $(element).fadeIn();
          $(element).addClass("is-invalid");
        });
      },

    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      username: "required",
      password: "required"
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      username: "Please enter your username",
      password: "Please enter your password",
      url: "Please enter a url"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: HTML in form action attribute to click any button to move this action URL ..... you can check javascript validation to us ajax call to solver your problem

Comment: Where is `unhighlight` callback function?  You call `highlight` but not `unhighlight` and this is big part of your problem.  `highlight` is called when invalid and adds the invalid class (and removes valid class).  `unhighlight` does the opposite, called when valid and adds the valid class (and removes invalid class).  Since you left it out, it reverts to the default `unhighlight` function.  And your `highlight` class is not removing the valid classes.

Comment: I will go and try and unhighlight! Thanks.